# Duplicated header on click on toggle panel extjs4

Tags: extjs, header, toggle, panel, expand

I have a problem with collapsible panels. I have a toolbar on top with the toggle icon but also if I click on panel's header it expand and the header is duplicated. Now if I click on the toggle button to collapse it only the duplicated header is collapsed.
Here's my code:

```
Ext.define('Pollini.ricercaTarghe', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    title: '<center>Ricerca per targa</center>',
    collapsed: true,
    region: 'north',
    id: 'ricercaTarghe',
    height: 255,
    layout: 'border',

    initComponent: function(){
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [ searchTarga, risTarghe ],
            tools: [
                {
                    type: 'toggle',
                    handler: function(){
                        me.toggleCollapse(true);
                    }
                }
            ],
            listeners: {
                expand: function(){
                    /* some stuff */
                }
            }

        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Here's an image
[image: Toggle Panel Error]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one. I really don't know why but it occurs upon rendering the panel you then collapsed panel. What I did was to give a timer 1 second or a couple millisecond then called toggleCollapse().

Something like this:

```
members.toggleCollapse(); // this will collapse the panel

// The timeout will then expand with the given time
setTimeout(function(){
    accessPanel.toggleCollapse();
    members.toggleCollapse();
}, 800}
```

Fortunately the duplicate header went away. Like I said I really dont know why as to specifics but this worked for me. Give a try.

Comment: I've tried it but if I click on panel's header (on the panel's title for example) it expands without waiting 800ms and the header is duplicated. If I click on the toggle tool after 800ms it expands.

Comment: collapsible: false, hideCollapseTool: true, floatable: false <-- add these properties in your collapsible panel.

Comment: I added these properties but now I can't collapse the panel

Comment: That way the only way to expand and collapse your panel will only be the button assigned to do so which in turn will always execute the settimout. I dont know if this specs fit for you but this is what I did.